# Dynamics CRM 2011 is it possible to upgrade only SSRS from 2008 to 2012?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We have Dynamics CRM 2011 on premise and SQL Server 2008 R2.

We would want to install SSRS 2012 on the reporting server but keep SQL Server 2008 R2 as the database for CRM and the reason is because we have that limitation with the maximum number of rows possible to export in Excel (~65k).

1. Is it possible?
2. Are the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Fetch XML based Custom Reports going to work afterwards?

Any information or links about this would be greatly appreciated.